# Why does my app not receive the WM_CREATE message?

Tags: vb6, subclassing, windows-messages

I want to get notified of new windows before they are shown.

Therefore I subclass my application and listen for the WM_CREATE message.

I am using Paul Caton's VB6 subclasser.

Subclassing and listening to Windows Messages usually works fine for me, but I just don't receive any WM_CREATE message.

Neither when I open any additional window in my app nor when other apps show new windows.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You subclass only one window? `WM_CREATE` is delivered to the created window, not to the creator.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644991(v=vs.85) on how to do what you want.